# Role-based authentication / permissions in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, authentication, permissions, sinatra, role-base-authorization

I am writing a web application in Ruby, using Sinatra. The application will have a number of restricted routes that users will not be permitted to access without authentication. I am using Warden for user authentication. It works well for authenticating users of a single type. However, I want users to have different levels of access. (Currently I want to at least be able to differentiate between regular users and administrators.) I imagine this is a common requirement, but I can't find any guidance for how to implement it in Sinatra. Is there a "standard" gem or approach for role-based authentication/permissions in Sinatra (or Ruby more generally)?

I am aware of the cancan gem for rails (not usable in Sinatra) and the sinatra-can gem (not maintained since 2011). I have also read about the concept of "scopes" in Warden. It seems like they may be what I need, but it's not clear from the Warden documentation whether/how they solve my problem.

Comment: Sinatra is deliberately sparse.  It expects that you will want to do a lot of this stuff for yourself.  To start with, it looks like you will need to store which users are of which type somewhere...